# Grouped Boxplot Alternate Color, Label and Tight Spacing Issue

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

With the following data (for a quick csv file generation, dataset [link](https://pastebin.com/0dZyThPx)):

[image: dataset]

and the following code:

```
df_all[['all', 'taste','fruit']].melt('fruit').boxplot(column=['value'], by=['fruit', 'variable'], rot=45, fontsize=11, patch_artist=True,
             color=dict(boxes='#053061', whiskers='#67001F', medians='#A7D0E4', caps='#67001F'),
             boxprops=dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8),
             flierprops=dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=0, marker='+'),
             medianprops=dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8),
             whiskerprops=dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8),
             capprops=dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8),
             showfliers=True, 
             grid=False,)
```

I get this abomination:

[image: abomination]

I want to achieve

1. alternate colors on boxplots (first blue as is, then red and every alternate one red)
2. label below every box plot
3. legend

something like:

[image]

Probably it is impossible to achieve an exact output, but any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to using seaborn, you can use [**`sns.boxplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and set the melted `variable` as `hue`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(
    data=df[['all', 'taste', 'fruit']].melt('fruit'),
    x='fruit',
    y='value',
    hue='variable',
    width=0.5,
    order=['apple', 'mango', 'orange'],
)
```

[image: seaborn grouped boxplot]

Comment: Wow, I really didn't think this was possible. Seaborn saves the day again, thanks!